# How to see Logcat output from Android Emteria OS over Raspberry Pi 3B?

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, adb, logcat

I install my developed app by copying the APK to the Raspberry using a USB memory stick, and not running it directly from the Android studio.

Because according to [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/android-raspberry-pi/) and [this](https://www.littlebird.com.au/learn/51/run-android-on-raspberry-pi), there seems to be no other way of doing it. (**Update: Proved to be wrong according to the accepted answer**)

When I connect the Raspberry to my PC using USB or the [ADB cable](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi#serial-console), it is not seen as a device, neither in Android studio or the ADB tool and when I use [PuTTY](https://www.putty.org/), I just get a blank console screen.

Now, I need to see the Logcat output of my android application that is installed over Emteria on Raspberry pi 3B in order to be able to debug my app.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: make sure app version that you have installed is debug able.

Comment: @AkashDubey It is a debug version not a release one. Isn't that correct?

Comment: Run `adb logcat` in terminal?

Comment: @lojza I get waiting for devices, cus it is not detected anywhere.

Comment: You can run it even on android. Are you able to connect via Ethernet/Wifi? Then from your pc `adb connect <IP of your device>` Check http://geomodule.com/sw-eng-notes/2018/12/23/raspberry-pi-how-to-install-emteria-os-android-google-play-and-synthesia/

Comment: @lojza I tried the Wifi option, and got it working! Now, I can even run my app directly from Android studio and see all logs. But, I still can't manage to make it work using the USB debugging cable.But, no problem now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems solution is connect via wifi and then:

```
adb connect <IP of your device>
```

More at http://geomodule.com/sw-eng-notes/2018/12/23/raspberry-pi-how-to-install-emteria-os-android-google-play-and-synthesia/

Comment: This solution allows you to install apps directly from android studio and see the Logcat from there too.